# $X$ is locally connected iff exists a basis of opens and connected

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

### $X$ is locally connected iff exists a basis of opens and connected

$(\Rightarrow)$ If $X$ is locally connected, then for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x\in X$, it exists an open and connected set $A$ such that  $x\in A\subseteq U$, thus i can consider the basis $B=\{ A\subseteq X :A \: \text{is open and connected }\}$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $B=\{ A\subseteq X :A \: \text{is open and connected }  \}$  be a basis of $X$,
and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x\in X$ then from the properties of the basis, it always exists a set $A\in B$ such that $x\in A\subseteq U$ and since $A$ is connected, $X$ is locally connected.

Comment: What's your official definition of $X$ being locally connected?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $X$ is called locally connected iff for every open n-b $U$ of $x$ it exists an open and connected $V$ of $X$ s.t $x\in V\subseteq U$

Comment: In that case there is nothing to prove, the definition is exactly what you have to prove.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma that's what I thought, idk why this was an exercise, thought I missed something

Comment: Chances are, your instructor was testing if you know the definition of a basis or of local connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of locally connected

> For every open neighbourhood $U$ of any $x$ there is an open and connected $V$ such that $x \in V \subseteq U$.

**exactly** says that the open and connected sets form a base for $X$. So nothing to prove. Just a restatement of the definitions.